# Taskbar and laucher disappeared

Tags: launcher, taskbar

I switched my laptop on , which runs on ubuntu 16.04, but the taskbar and launcher were missing. I opened firefox using terminal but still there is no option to maximize the window or doing any changes to it. It was working fine 10 hrs ago. What should I do?
Also I didn't install any software recently that can do this to the system, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring up a terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run `unity`.  This will reload the desktop settings.